# Slow HTTP POST Vulnerabity for Apache

Tags: security, apache

Does anybody know if there is a fix for Slow HTTP POST Vulnerabity for Apache?
http://www.darkreading.com/vulnerability-management/167901026/security/attacks-breaches/228000532/researchers-to-demonstrate-new-attack-that-exploits-http.html

Here is a tool to test the vulnerabilty:
http://code.google.com/p/slowhttptest/

And here is documentation for Apache Module mod_reqtimeout, which I believe might help:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [ModSecurity](http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2011/07/advanced-topic-of-the-week-mitigating-slow-http-dos-attacks.html):

> For the purposes of identifying RUDY types of attacks, we can add the
>   following directive to our Apache configs:
>
> **RequestReadTimeout header=30, body=30**
>
> This places a threshold of 30 seconds to completely receive the
>   request body data.  If the data is not received by that time, Apache
>   will issue a 408 Request-Timeout status code.  With this directive in
>   place, we then add in some new ModSecurity rules that do the
>   following:

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [mod_antiloris](http://mod-antiloris.sourceforge.net/) to prevent this. There are a number of other ways, but this might be a better solution.